# Confused on how to use .not() in Jquery

Tags: javascript

I hope I can explain this in a way that makes sense.

I have an array named **temp**. The **values for temp will always be different**, but this array will **always ONLY have 2 elements**.

For Example:

```
temp[0] = 10
temp[1] = 14
```

The values "10" and "14" represent indexes in a different array called gameboard. And the values in the gameboard indexes indicated matching numbers.

For Example:

```
gameboard[10] = 3
gameboard[14] = 3
```

The goal is to have a value for variables: **index1** and **index2**

The "temp" array is populated by looping through the gameboard. So **index1** might be temp[0] OR temp[1]. This will be different every turn. But ultimately, "index1" is the needle, and "temp" is the haystack.

For Example:

```
var index_found = $.inArray(needle, temp);
```

This will return either a **0** or a **1** (0 does not mean false in this case)

```
0 = temp[0] 
1 = temp[1]
```

**THIS IS WHAT I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH:**
I need a way to say "NOT" *that* index.

If "inArray" returns 1, I actually want the value 0.

If "inArray" returns 0, I actually want the value 1.

So, if I were to put this in a conditional statement, it would look like this:

```
if (index_found == 1) {
    index2 = 0;
} else if (index_found == 0) {
    index2 = 1;
}
```

I mean... obviously, the conditional statement works. But I feel like there is a better/more efficient/professional way to write this out.
I hope that makes sense. >.<

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, the main .js file is basically all jquery. So technically, yea this is just basic javascript. Initially, I was thinking the solution would lie somewhere with jquery's .not() or .filter() or something

Comment: `.not()` and `.filter()` in jQuery are for working with jQuery collections, not arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is honestly a bit confusing, but if your question is how to make this code more elegant:

```
if (index_found == 1) {
    index2 = 0;
} else if (index_found == 0) {
    index2 = 1;
}
```

You could replace this with:

```
index2 = 1 - index_found;
```

If `index_found` is 1, then the result will be 0, if `index_found` is 0, the result will be 1.

You could also do:

```
index2 = index_found === 1 ? 0 : 1;
```

Which just says if `index_found` is 1, then set the value to 0, otherwise 1 (look up ternary operators for more details).

Comment: I'm sorry it was confusing, but you were able to read my mind! So thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of this >.< I feel like a herp derp